# How does Python's statsmodel ARMA fit work?

Tags: time-series, arma, statsmodels

[Here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA.fit.html) is the documentation for statsmodel's ARMA fit function. My issue is that it does not specify the form of the model it is fitting, i.e. is it fitting $a(L)y_t = b(L)\epsilon_t$ or is it fitting the regression form
[image]

It's a bit confusing because statsmodel's ARMA generation assumes the form $a(L)y_t = b(L)\epsilon_t$, but the "no constant" option makes it unclear.

Comment: Since the documentation says ARMA(p,q), I think it has the form that you describe. It has the option to include or exclude the constant c.

Comment: I mean, both are ARMA(p,q), one is just more succinct than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "constant" option in the fit returns the mean, from which the actual constant can be recovered using $\mu = \beta_0/(1- \beta_1 - \cdots - \beta_p)$.

Comment: Is this behavior documented? I couldn't find it on the package's website and spent days trying to figure out what the heck is going on. Thanks